# How to add a new python package to Odoo server

Tags: python, odoo-8

I would like to install new python modules like xlrd and xlwt for Excel handling operations. How can i install these to packages into odoo server

Comment: `sudo pip install xlrd`

Comment: in odoo where i will run this command?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run command in Linux terminal :

Open Linux Terminal and type that command,

```
sudo pip install xlrd
```

Comment: This is how we generally add python packages. But adding packages to odoo server is different